# getting some tr values dynamically with jquery and passe them with ajax to php

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass some td values to ajax call when pressing the button "Delete"
How can I do that with jquery?

```
<table>
       <tr>
          <td class="datao">first column</td>
          <td class="data1">first column</td>
          <td class="data2">first column</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td class="datao">xzczxc</td>
          <td class="data1">xzczxc</td>
          <td class="data2">xzczxc</td>
          <td>   
             <input type="button" class="deleteRow" value="Delete" />
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td class="datao">xzczxc</td>
          <td class="data1">xzczxc</td>
          <td class="data2">xzczxc</td>
          <td>   
             <input type="button" class="deleteRow" value="Delete" />
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td class="datao">xzczxc</td>
          <td class="data1">xzczxc</td>
          <td class="data2">xzczxc</td>
          <td>   
             <input type="button" class="deleteRow" value="Delete" />
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td class="datao">xzczxc</td>
          <td class="data1">xzczxc</td>
          <td class="data2">xzczxc</td>
          <td>   
             <input type="button" class="deleteRow" value="Delete" />
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td class="datao">xzczxc</td>
          <td class="data1">xzczxc</td>
          <td class="data2">xzczxc</td>
          <td>   
             <input type="button" class="deleteRow" value="Delete" />
          </td>
       </tr>
</table>
```

UPDATE:
Supposing that I want to grab the value of input type=text inside of the 's.

HTML Example:

```
 <table>
           <tr>
              <td class="datao">
                 <select class="someclass">
                    <option value="asdsa">somevalue</option>
                 </select>
              </td>
              <td class="datao">
                 <input type="text" value="eqw" />
              </td>
              <td class="datao">
                 <input type="text" value="gfg" />
              </td>
              <td>   
                 <input type="button" class="deleteRow" value="Delete" />
              </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td class="datao">
                 <select class="someclass">
                    <option value="wq">somevalue</option>
                 </select>
              </td>
              <td class="datao">
                 <input type="text" value="hfd" />
              </td>
              <td class="datao">
                 <input type="text" value="vcv" />
              </td>
              <td>   
                 <input type="button" class="deleteRow" value="Delete" />
              </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td class="datao">
                 <select class="someclass">
                    <option value="cva">somevalue</option>
                 </select>
              </td>
              <td class="datao">
                 <input type="text" value="ewd" />
              </td>
              <td class="datao">
                 <input type="text" value="asad" />
              </td>
              <td>   
                 <input type="button" class="deleteRow" value="Delete" />
              </td>
           </tr>
 </table>
```

jquery's code:

Let's say I want to grab select's value each row of data...

```
$('input.deleteRow').live('click', function() {
        var values = [];

        $(this).closest('tr').find("select").each(function() {
            values.push($(this).attr('value'));
        });

        //Confirm 
        //the ok stores true or false returned by confirm!
        var ok = confirm("Are you sure...?");

        //testing for true
        if(ok){
            $.post("phpscript.php", { someName:values[0] }, function(data) {
                if(data == '1'){
                    alert("something");
                    location.reload();              
                }
                else
                    alert("something else, error probably");
            });
        }

    });
```

If you want to grab select and input type="text" just need to do: ...find("select, input[type=text]")...

This is my contribute to the community.
Anyway, I would like to find an elegant way of sending the data to the php script give a hand on it.

Comment: Which TD values? How much of this have you done so far? What does the PHP file look like? Is it your PHP file or are you posting it to an external web service? What do you want to happen exactly?

Comment: Well the php file is irrelevant, it will receive the values sent by ajax call when the button click event fires. So I want to pass the values from the three <td> cells inside the <tr> to ajax...

Answer (score 1):

May use http://www.datatables.net/ - much easier than program all by your self?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to attach an event handler to each of the input buttons that will go to the button's parent (`<td>`) and then go to that node's siblings (the other `<td>`s). For each of these you will get the inner HTML for the respective `<td>` and then figure out some way to pair these all together (delimited string maybe?)

```
$('input.deleteRow').live('click', function() {

    var returnString = '';

    $(this).parent().siblings().each(function() {
        returnString += $(this).html();
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'somephpurlhere.php',
        data: returnString
    }).success(function() {
        //dosomething
    }).fail(function() {
        //dosomethingelse
    });

});
```

You will need to modify the .ajax call to suit your needs as you haven't expressed how you are handling responses, etc.

If you want to check if a given DOM element contains a td or an input then you could replace the .each functionality as follows:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('td').length > 0)
        resultString += $(this).find('td').html();
    else if ($(this).find('input').length > 0)
        resultString += $(this).find('input').val();
    else
        resultString += $(this).html();
});
```

Comment: Suppose that inside the <td> is an <input> or a <select> how can I get the value from it?

Comment: Thanks for all, check my UPDATE. And consider review it and make it better. ;) in particularly the sending data case which I don't like It's kind of messy...